# Building VAR (Vector Autoregression) model with dummy variables in R

Tags: r, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I came across vars package in [R] and it seems the package does everything I need for a VAR model. The only exception is that I need to define dummy variables. For example think that my dependent vector has n elements and I need to estimate (eliminate) the impact of Christmas holiday on the first element. I define a dummy variable with 1 at Christmas day and 0 at other days, but if I add this into the dependent variables vector, model parameters become extensively large. Is there any other way to define dummies for one variable in this package?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Could you explain in more detail what you mean by *I require to define dummy variables for one element of the vector*? (I suggest editing the original post rather than posting a comment in response.)

Comment: Thanks. Edited. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: So it looks that the functionality of the "vars" package is fine, and the problem is actually in your particular application where you do not find the estimation results convincing; is that right?

Comment: I don't see a package called "VAR" on CRAN. Could it actually be "vars"?

Comment: Thanks Richard. That's correct, the package name is vars. Edited in the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can include those dummies as exogeneous (`exogen`) variables:

```r
    varfit <- vars::VAR(varmat, p = 2, 
                       exogen = cbind(black.friday = 
                       data$black.friday, cyber.monday = 
                       data$cyber.monday))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add them as exogenous variable, or you can decompose the time series and analyze the seasonal component around Christmas. Maybe, even consider adding a dummy fixed effect for around the time you see seasonality.